# Pagination custom url in codeigniter-4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I created a method in a model of CI4 to query a search results. I need to paginate search results but the URL not provide results. I need to standard way for pagination in CI4.
Here is model method -

```
<?php
public function search($key)
    {   

        $builder = $this->table('apps_common_all');
        $builder->Like('name',$key,'after');
        $query   = $builder->paginate(51);
        return $query;
    }

?>
```

controller method is -

```
<?php 
public function result()
    {   
        $key = $this->request->getVar('s');
        $apps = new AppsModel();
        $data = [
                'items'     => $apps->search($key),
                'pager'     => $apps->pager,
            ];
        return view('search/index',$data);
    }
?>
```

Pagination code in view page

```
<?php if ($pager) :?>
    <?php $pagi_path=getenv('pagi_path').'search_result'; ?>
    <?php $pager->setPath($pagi_path); ?>
    <?= $pager->links() ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

when pagination link clicked the url not provide results

```
http://myshahadat.com/demo/apkdownload/search_result?s=a&page=2
```

and my route is

```
<?php $routes->get('/search_result', 'Search::result'); ?>
```

Comment: I got the solutions that I mistake to changed the path `getenv('pagi_path')` in .env file.